# Bad type on operand stack: Generic String return type for switch condition

Tags: java, eclipse, verifyerror

I experienced a weird behavior of Java 1.8.311 (also older ones) and how it handles generic return types in combination with switch-statements:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "test";

    switch (Objects.requireNonNull(test)) {
    case "test":
      test = "OK";
      break;
    default:
      test = "NOK";
    }

    System.err.println(test);
  }
```

On execution the JVM seems to exit immediately with a JNI error.
Can this be considered as a Java bug?

Edit: Stack-Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    forTestCase/Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @9: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/String'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @9
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/Object' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 1210 4c2b b800 1259 4db6 0018 ab00 0000
    0x0000010: 0000 0026 0000 0001 0036 4492 0000 0014
    0x0000020: 2c12 10b6 001e 9a00 06a7 0009 1222 4ca7
    0x0000030: 0006 1224 4cb2 0026 2bb6 002c b1       
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@32,Object[#25],Object[#25])
    same_frame(@44)
    same_frame(@50)
    chop_frame(@53,1)

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
```

Comment: And it works with a redundant `switch ((String)...)`?

Comment: (There is no other code with loss of generic typing like `new ArrayList()`?)

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this with Java 1.8.0_291.

Comment: @JoopEggen I don't use the args-array.  in the first line in the method I declared a string 'test' ;-)

Comment: After compiling it with javac instead of launching it out of Eclipse it worked. Weird...

Comment: Probably [this error](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576008) which will be fixed in 2021-12. Eclipse uses its own Java compiler so it can be different from javac. Looks like the generics in `Objects.requireNonNull` has confused to compiler.